# enable_if U is a descendant of Interface<T>

Tags: c++, templates, interface, c++14, template-specialization

Up to **C++14**

In my example I have a `begin()` for a custom iterator. So far I have this

```
template<typename T>
inline auto
begin(ISomeIterator<T> &it)
  -> RangeForISomeIterator<ISomeIterator<T>>
{
  return it;
}

template<typename T>
inline auto
begin(ISomeConstIterator<T> &it)
  -> RangeForISomeConstIterator<ISomeConstIterator<T>>
{
  return it;
}
```

I would like to change this to use the static type of the caller context. Let's call the actual implementations `TheIterator` and `TheConstIterator` that are the descendants of `ISomeIterator<Apple>` and `ISomeConstIterator<Apple>` respectively. I would like to create a `RangeForISomeIterator<TheIterator>` when  `begin(theIt)` is called and `RangeForISomeConstIterator<TheConstIterator>` when `begin(theConstIt)` is called.

```
begin(U &it)
// where U is a descendant of ISomeIterator<T>

begin(U &it)
// where U is a descendant of ISomeConstIterator<T>
```

Comment: I don't understand this question. `begin()` takes a range and returns an iterator - it looks like you're taking an iterator and returning a range. And it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish either.

Comment: You *probably shouldn't* try to shoehorn a *different* idea of iteration than what `std` has

Comment: Probably I inherited some code. :-)  If we forget about iterators, the original question is still interesting

Comment: Also there's no point in `std::forward`ing an lvalue

Comment: @Caleth Dropped.

Answer (score 2):

Just declare the proper [`Iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator) members, and dispatch on `std::is_const<std::iterator_traits<IT>::value_type>`.

```
namespace detail
{
    template<typename IT>
    inline auto begin(IT&& it, std::false_type)
      -> RangeForISomeIterator<IT>
    {
      return std::forward<IT>(it);
    }

    template<typename IT>
    inline auto begin(IT&& it, std::true_type)
      -> RangeForISomeConstIterator<IT>
    {
      return std::forward<IT>(it);
    }
}

template<typename IT>
inline auto begin(IT&& it)
  -> decltype(detail::begin(std::forward<IT>(it), std::is_const<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type>{}))
{
  return detail::begin(std::forward<IT>(it), std::is_const<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type>{});
}
```

P.S. Why do you have iterators (publicly) descending from *anything*?

Comment: Re P..S: We cannot have templates on APIs that are hiding implementations.

If we forget about iterators, the original question is still interesting. I like your answer for the given example I presented.